How to install Anydesk on Ubuntu server session based
I have set up a VPS running Ubuntu Server 24.04 and configured it to a session based RDP connection for multiple users to work on simultaneously.
I am attempting to install anydesk on some of the user profiles, since the team members prefer using anydesk to connect over other solutions. Usually we use Remmina, however some are adamant about using anydesk.
However, I have encountered a problem, when I download Anydesk.deb file from the official page, and run it through Software Installer, it attempts to run it through the root user rather than "example_user".
I've attempted to do a local install only on "example_user" by simply extracting the deb file to the users directory and creating a desktop entry for them to launch it, however it yields no results. Now whenever I am attempting to launch it, nothing happens, no error codes, even the root user does not have any anydesk processes running. So I am completely confused as to how I can go about installing and using anydesk on specific users.
If anyone can give any advice on how to resolve this, or perhaps any hints on what may be causing the problem, I'd be very grateful for any and all input!
As I said previously, no error messages appear, so I truly have no clue where to even start.

All packaged software requires elevated permissions to install. It doesn't meant it won't be available for normal users once installed. What you describe here is nonsensical.

Could you try the Generic Linux (64-bit) version of Anydesk from their download page instead of using the Debian package extract? Also, could you check ~/.anydesk/anydesk.trace log file?
